# WordPress orderby a custum field, sort listing by custom field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I am using this code to display listing sorted by "postnr", `postnr` is custom field.

```
$config = [
    "s" => $_GET["s"],
    "order" => "ASC",
    "orderby" => "postnr"
];
```

How can I sort listing `orderby` a custom field "postnr" in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` and define the `meta_key` as `'meta_key' => 'postnr',`.

Here is the code:

```
$config = [
    "s" => $_GET["s"],
    "order" => "ASC",
    'meta_key' => 'postnr',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value' //or 'meta_value_num'
];
```

Reference:: [Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Hope this helps!